# Kendo Ui Dropdown combine dataTextField

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

How do I combine dropdown multiple value went display in dropdown. Example `Surname + Name`

[FULL DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/UTIfEKoq)

```
<script>
$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: [
        { Surname: "Sir1", Name: "Parent1", Id: 1 },
        { Surname: "Sir2", Name: "Parent2", Id: 2 }
    ],
    optionLabel: "- Please Select -",
    dataTextField: "Surname"+"Name",
    dataValueField: "Id"
});
</script>
```

Comment: define another array by combain the two field to make one

Comment: @dontbannedmeagain did my solution worked out for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Template for the column

```
$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: [
        { Surname: "Sir1", Name: "Parent1", Id: 1 },
        { Surname: "Sir2", Name: "Parent2", Id: 2 }
    ],
    optionLabel: "- Please Select -",
    dataTextField: "Surname"+"Name",
    dataValueField: "Id",
  template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
});
```

Your html

```
<input id="dropdownlist" />
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <span>
    #: Surname # #: Name #
  </span>
</script>
```

Here is some documentation

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/configuration/template